# Make modifyable lists of object variables and keep list with variables in sync

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class with different variables. I want to let the user modify this variables. The user should read and write values in e.g. a `DataGrid`. I want to separate some variables to different `DataGrid`s.

```
class MyClass
{
  int _number1; //show in DataGrid 1
  int _number2; //show in DataGrid 1
  string _name; //show in DataGrid 1
  Adress _adress; //show in DataGrid 1

  int _anotherNumber1; //show in DataGrid 2
  int _anotherNumber2; //show in DataGrid 2

  int _privateNumber //do not show the user
}
```

### My approach

For grouping the variables, I currently use a (modified) `Dictionary` class.

```
//ObservableDictionary is a modified Dictionary class
private ObservableDictionary<string, object> _dataGrid1Properties;

public ObservableDictionary<string, object> DataGrid1Properties
{
  get { return _dataGrid1Properties; }
}

//... other Grid lists

public MyClass()
{
  _dataGrid1Properties = new ObservableDictionary<string, object>();
  _dataGrid1Properties.Add("Number1", _number1);
  //...
}
```

Now I can update the list, when a value of my object changed:

```
int _number1;

public int Number1
{
  get { return _number1; }
  set { _number1 = value; _dataGrid1Properties["Number1"] = value; }
}
```

My problem is the update of the object variable when the list is modified. I have no reference to my object. But I cannot write something like `ObservableDictionary<string, ref object>` or something like that...

### Question

How can I update the value of the object when the `Dictionary` value is changed?

Comment: Subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).  But, I think you'd be better off with a ViewModel class.

Comment: I can't see the benefit of `ObservableDictionary` used to group the properties. Different DataGrids can bind to same instance of `MyClass`, the binding code will be simpler without using `ObservableDictionary`;

Comment: @kennyzx I use one dictionary to use a part of the object as "dynamic object" where the user can remove and add some own properties. My idea was: when I have it, I can use it for the rest too. I also have many classes, I'm not sure if it will be simpler... and maybe it will be harder to maintain because I need to change the binding code that is in another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as Peter said, this can be achieved by subscribing to the [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event

```
public MyClass()
{
    _dataGrid1Properties = new ObservableDictionary<string, object>();            
    _dataGrid1Properties.Add("Name", _name);
    //...add other properties
    //then wire up the CollectionChanged event
    _dataGrid1Properties.CollectionChanged += _dataGrid1Properties_CollectionChanged;
}

void _dataGrid1Properties_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
            {
                if (e.NewItems != null)
                {
                    if (e.NewItems.Count > 0 && e.NewItems[0] is KeyValuePair<string, object>)
                    {
                        KeyValuePair<string, object> item = (KeyValuePair<string, object>)e.NewItems[0];
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("key = {0}, new value = {1}", item.Key, item.Value));
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            {
                //new items added  
                //break;
            }
        //cases for Remove/Reset.
            //break;
    } 
}
```

Shipped versions of .NET BCL do not have a `ObservableDictionary` class, I search on the web and test [this one](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2010/12/26/observabledictionarylttkey-tvaluegt-c/) and it seems to be working, however, fully test it if you want to adopt it in your code since it may have bugs.

The data for the event is exposed by the [`NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter, you can check what is causing this change (Add/Remove/Replace...) by checking its `Action` property, and by checking the `NewItems/OldItems` properties you can get the changed data.

Comment: How can I identify what variable I have to change?

Comment: I am not sure if you understood me. Let's imagine I have another variable `_myVar` in my class. I add it: `_dataGrid1Properties.Add("SecondVar", _myVar);`. Now I change it in the list. I get an event (Replace) back. How can I identify now that I need to change `_myVar`? Do I have to do it like: `switch(item.Key) { case("SecondVar"): _myVar = item.Value; }`?

Comment: yes, that is what I mean. since the binding is between datagrid and the observabledictionary, MyClass object is not the binding source. When UI is updated, the observabledictionary is updated via binding (no code is required), and notify the MyClass object to pickup the change (you have to do it manually).